# use FCM in xamarin.forms without native class

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

How can I use FCM on xamarin.forms
without native classes and without dependency service.
use it on android studio but can not use FCM on xamarin.forms

Comment: Not possible without dependency services and native classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. Xamarin.Forms does not provide any APIs for this. Therefore, you will have to provide functionality for this yourself.

Since wiring up these notifications is pretty platform-specific, you will need to implement "native classes" as you call them.